# Python script to follow Twitter user IDs

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to create a little python script to follow Twitter user IDs from a textfile (one per line, in numeric format e.g. 217275660, 30921943, etc.). I took a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374427/how-can-i-find-follow-requsted-users-with-python-twitter) on stack exchange to make the code below using the 'try/except' answer, but I am getting an error "NameError: name 'TwitterError' is not defined"...

Anyone know how to clear this issue up and fix the code? I feel like it should be pretty simple but haven't used the Twitter API before.

```
# Script to follow Twitter users from text file containing user IDs (one per line)

# Header stuff I've just thrown in from another script to authenticate

import json
import time
import tweepy
import pprint
from tweepy.parsers import RawParser
from auth import TwitterAuth
from datetime import datetime

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TwitterAuth.consumer_key, TwitterAuth.consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(TwitterAuth.access_token, TwitterAuth.access_token_secret)

rawParser = RawParser()

api = tweepy.API(auth_handler = auth, parser = rawParser)

# Follow everyone from list?!

with open('to_follow.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            api.CreateFriendship(userID)
        except TwitterError:
            continue

print "Done."
```

Comment: Well where is `TwitterError` defined? Do you mean [`tweepy.TweepError`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/error.py#L10)?

Comment: Ah yes, they are using python-twitter, whooops.

Comment: As a follow up, assuming this is the actual code being run, ```api.CreateFriendship(userID)``` might cause you some headache as ```userID``` is currently undefined (it was never pulled out of ```line```). Easy fix as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is may be because the `tweepy` throws error of type `TweepError` so you need to catch `TweepError` instead of `TwitterError`

```
for line in f:
    try:
        api.CreateFriendship(userID)
    except TweepError,e:
        continue
```